# What is the origin of Kumbha Mela?

Tags: scripture, festivals, kumbh-mela, pilgrimage

Once every 12 years, the Maha Kumbh is celebrated at [Haridwar](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Haridwar_Kumbh_Mela), [Prayag](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Allahabad_Kumbh_Mela), [Nasik](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Nashik-Trimbakeshwar_Simhastha) and [Ujjain](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Ujjain_Simhastha). It is generally believed that the reason for celebrating Maha Kumbh at those 4 places is because the Amrita (Nectar) at the time of [Samudra Manthan](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Samudra_manthan) has fallen on those places.

Wikipedia [says](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Kumbh_Mela#Mythological_origin):

> According to medieval Hindu mythology, the origin of the festival can be found in the ancient legend of samudra manthan. The legend tells of a battle between the Devas and Asuras for amrita, the drink of immortality. During samudra manthan, or churning of the ocean, amrita was produced and placed in a kumbha (pot). To prevent the asuras (malevolent beings) from seizing the amrita, a divine carrier flew away with the pot. In one version of the legend, the carrier of the kumbha is the divine physician Dhanavantari, who stops at four places where the Kumbh Mela is celebrated. In other re-tellings, the carrier is Garuda, Indra or Mohini, who spills the amrita at four places.

I want to know if there's a proper scriptural version of the origin of the Kumbha Mela.

Answer (score 0):

Your title question 1) "what is the origin".
concluding question 2) "does it have scriptural evidence".

1. The origin of Kumbh Mela is from at least 1399 and retroactively mimics designs from older scriptural Magha Mela and other opportunities to ritually cleanse or enact penance. Magha Mela is different because it is astrologically based and must adhere to geographical constraint.

The purpose of festivals are to please Gods or Goddesses and there should be instructions of how to do them properly.

2. Both Kumbh Mela does not have specific scriptural instruction and Samudra Manthan has not had scriptural evidence of being re-enacted as part of a religious celebration, Kumbh rather includes a mix of many instructions and activities from other designs. Even if instruction was passed orally, there would come a cyclical time where our minds weaken and so would necessitate written instruction.

However, Kumbh is the worlds largest religious gathering, where faithful can act out purification rituals. In 2019, Kumbh had 50 million participants. If wanted to, it could literally move mountains.

Answer (score 0):

Poorna Kumbh and Mahakumbh are festivals associated to saints who seek praise of God. The venue of such Kumbh is cited to  Haridwar but is followed all over India in different places according to a 12+ year celestial phenomenon.
In South Indian ocean it is celebrated for Hari Avatar. It is followed wherever Hari Avatar surfed Earth.

Answer (score 0):

History of kumbhmela dates back to 5000 years.
Shiva came down from brahmalok (soul world) to save humans from sinful deeds.

so he is called as the liberator. The knowledge he taught to brahma was the secret to remove humans from sin.

The conference of shiva, the God and the humans in earth was called as the kumbh mela.

Followere remember this occasion as the meeting point of gyan ganga and other rivers. that is shiva, the supreme soul and the childrens (other souls)

Comment: Your answer could be improved with additional supporting information. Please [edit] to add further details, such as citations or documentation, so that others can confirm that your answer is correct. You can find more information on how to write good answers [in the help center](/help/how-to-answer).