# Is there any mention of Amrit falling at different places after quarrel between Dev and Daityas

Tags: samudra-manthan, kumbh-mela

I saw an episode of  'Shiv Mahapuran' serial and there it was shown when Amrit came out of Samudra Manthan, Dev and Daityas were running after one another, quarrelling and snatching the Amrit holding vessel(Kumbh) and then Some Amrit fell at different occasions at different places. There were 4 places mentioned, river Ganga in Haridwar and Prayag, Godavari and Shipra rivers. And therefore these places have Kumbh Snaan at different times.

I wanted to know which book has this story of Amrit falling at these/more places. Also, can we calculate the time gap between these Kumbh Snaan such that we know exactly for how much time Dev and Daityas were running/quarrelling for Amrit.

Comment: Related [What is the origin of Kumbha Mela?](https://hinduism.stackexchange.com/questions/16552/what-is-the-origin-of-kumbha-mela).

Comment: Does this answer your question? [What is the origin of Kumbha Mela?](https://hinduism.stackexchange.com/questions/16552/what-is-the-origin-of-kumbha-mela)